# Migration to Hibernate 4, @Inheritance and @GeneratedValue misunderstandings

Tags: java, inheritance, orm, hibernate-annotations, hibernate-4.x

I upgraded my web application to use Hibernate 4. After that I got some problems and I need help with them.

I have one base class for my domain objects, looks like this:

```
@MappedSuperclass 
public class BaseDomainObject implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column
    protected Integer id;

    public Integer getId() {
            return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Then, I have a lot of entities, like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="[user]")
public class User extends BaseDomainObject {

    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String      firstName;
    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String      lastName;

    ....
}
```

And i have some inheritance between entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="record_data")
@Polymorphism(type=PolymorphismType.EXPLICIT)
public class RecordData extends BaseDomainObject {
    ....
}


@Entity
@Table(name="auto_data")
@Polymorphism(type=PolymorphismType.EXPLICIT)
public class AutoData extends RecordData {

}
```

When i make hql query i get this exception

```
 Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid column name 'DTYPE'.
```

In hibernate source code I saw that if entity has parents hibernate put on SINGLE_TABLE inheritance  by default, so in each query it concatenate DiscriminatorColumn, but i have no discriminator column, because each class is mapped to different table.

In order to solve this problem i put this annotation on my entities:

```
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
```

But after that i got another exeption

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Cannot use identity column key generation with <union-subclass> mapping for: bla.bla.RecordData
```

I found solution in web for this. It needs to change strategy of @GeneratedValue in my BaseDomainObject to TABLE

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE)
```

But this caused to another exception

```
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'hibernate_sequences'.
```

All table in my DB have an auto increment id.. So i don't want that hibernate will manage it..

Do I miss something ?

Comment: thanks!  that solved my problem were my hib 5 annot jpa mapped classes do some interriting, but always each has its own table/no discriminator...  InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS

Answer (score 0):

Some explanations:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Cannot use identity column
key generation with <union-subclass> mapping for: bla.bla.RecordData
```

The reason is, if you've got inherited entities in multiple tables, there is not way to use an identity column to generate keys (as this would probably generate the same key in different columns). Just imagine if You'd try to retrieve all BaseDomainObjects in a query, it would not be possible to have non-conflicting primary keys this way.

```
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name
'hibernate_sequences'.
```

You have set the ID generation strategy to TABLE but for some reason, hibernate did not create a table to store these IDs. You'd need to create it manually or find out why hibernate is not creating it on startup.

Some suggestions:

- Identity columns and inheritance does not play well as you've tried it. You should try @Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED) probably, as this would create a table for the base class with an identity column, and store the rest of the attributes in other tables.
- If the above fails, use sequences, by specifying @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)

Comment: JOINED is not a solution. With SEQUENCE I Get "com.softrunner.init.SrtSQLServerDialect does not support sequences".. So I understand that I should to roll back to Hibernate 3..

Comment: Probably too late, but what's the problem with "JOINED"?